VS Code return "Missing fullName on CustomLabel in \force-app\main\default\labels\CustomLabels.labels-meta.xml" no matter what I tried to download
My C drive crashed, so I had to re-install everything.
I downloaded the newest version of VS code. In the beginning, everything seems all good until I tried to download newly added stuff from the Org Browser. I tried to download newly added custom metadata, but it gave me this error: "Missing fullName on CustomLabel in \force-app\main\default\labels\CustomLabels.labels-meta.xml".
I was not trying to download the Custom Labels at all. Then I tried to retrieve the Custom Labels from source but I've got the same error. However, if I try to retrieve from source for any other existing modified items, then it is retrieved successfully.
The output for customLabel is
16:20:46.23 Starting SFDX: Retrieve This Source from Org

Missing fullName on CustomLabel in \force-app\main\default\labels\CustomLabels.labels-meta.xml

In the Org Browser, if I tried to download any existing metadata:

First I get a pop up saying "Are you sure you want to overwrite ...?"
if I click on the Overwrite button, the output screen shows the same Missing fullname on CustomLable error, even I was not trying to download customLabel at all.

Can anyone help?
In summary, I try to download newly added metadata from salesforce to VSCode from source control. It is supposed to download the XML files but it does not work anymore.
